# Is this device technically feasible?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

I'm a software engineer and new to hardware. Please bear with me.

I'm building out a Proof of Concept for a device and I would like to understand the feasibility around the concept from a device perspective.

**What I need:**

- A device with dimensions of max 2cm x 2cm
- The device needs to have a SoraCom embedded sim (https://www.soracom.io/soracom-global-iot-sim-datasheet/)
- The device needs to have an NFC tag.
- The device should NOT be battery operated.
- The device should be able to power on and send a signal via the embedded sim when separating two tiny magnets.

**Problem:**

- We need to be able to identify if a high end bottle of wine has been opened or not.

**Proposed solution:**

- Install the device in the bottle cap and have two magnets that separates when the bottle cap is separated from the bottle.
- When separating the bottle cap from the bottle the magnetic energy should power on the device for a brief moment and send a signal from the embedded sim.

Once the embedded sim has fired a signal I can trigger a webhook, which is the ultimate end-goal: Trigger a webhook upon separation of bottle and bottle cap.

Comment: What would the embedded SIM do? It can't do anything without power and if you want communication to happen, the SIM needs a battery powered radio module around it.

Comment: SIMs don't send signals. SIMs are only data storage modules which need to be paired with a radio module to be of much use.

Comment: Briefly: **No, there isn't enough energy in separating small magnets to power up a transmitter**  What's the NFC for?  Batteries are really the only practical small method for delivering enough power to do the transmission, regardless of what kind of SIM you might have.

Comment: FWIW, it's bad practice to include anything that includes solutions in a needs statement.  It will really stifle innovation.  Work hard to find your real needs.

Comment: To @ScottSeidman's point, let me state the question differently (I didn't want it to be this vague, but I take the point)

Problem to solve: Upon separating a bottle cap from a bottle, I need to send a webhook to a webserver. The constraint is that the solution must be 2x2cm max in size (to fit inside bottle cap) and cannot rely on a battery as it will, potentially, contaminate the liquid in the bottle.

Comment: Put the bottle in a locked safe. Send a notification when somebody opens the safe.

Comment: you would under no circumstances put electronics *inside* the bottle – nothing goes there than the wine and the cork. Anything else would be counteracting the whole point of your device. So, what you need to design is kind of a "chastity belt" for the cork, and that makes the whole thing less space- and energy-constrained, as well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - "you would under no circumstances put electronics inside the bottle"

How so? 

Also, I don't understand "So, what you need to design is kind of a "chastity belt" for the cork, and that makes the whole thing less space- and energy-constrained, as well" - Can you elaborate?

Comment: It seems that a purely mechanical design could used instead.  I am thinking a small metal ball in a glass tube tube with a one-way gate in the tube.  The metal ball would be at the top of the tube when the cap is installed in the bottle.  When the cap is removed, the magnet pulls the ball through the one-way gate, leaving the ball at the bottom.  As long as the ball is visible through the neck of the bottle, it will be obvious if the bottle had been opened.

Comment: @Andy your mission is to protect the integrity of the wine. Hence, you do not put electronics in there. That seems very intuitive to me. How often do you see electronics in direct contact with other foodstuff, say yoghurt? Wine is a lot worse, because it's also fairly corrosive and aggressive towards polymer materials. You very much avoid putting electronics close to that stuff – there's a reason bottles are made of glass, and one of the major (if not **the** major) failure points in wine preservation is wine-induced degradation of the cork.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Extremely well put argument. Thank you. This helps me. So taking this constraint into account, do you have any ideas on how you could trigger a webhook?

Comment: @SteveMathwig I like your thinking. However, it's a hard requirement to have a webhook sent as part of the bottle being opened, so the manufacturers know if the bottle has been opened or not - remotely, not in possession of the bottle.

Comment: I already wrote that in a [comment above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/673584/is-this-device-technically-feasible?noredirect=1#comment1793767_673584).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "So, what you need to design is kind of a "chastity belt" for the cork, and that makes the whole thing less space- and energy-constrained, as well"

How would such a setup enable me to send a signal to the internet?

Comment: By the way, if I were to buy any kind of luxury item for a couple thousand euros, I'd be *very* much opposed to anyone being notified when I make use of that; that's private. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147155/discussion-between-andy-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: @Andy Just skimming I find I've no idea if you are looking to refine some kind of idea that currently doesn't have a specific consumer and that you'll then go looking to market whatever you come up with after you have it and can show it or otherwise if you already have a specific customer in mind. If the latter, then we need to know ***exactly*** what kind of business it is and what and why they feel they have a problem to solve that is sufficient to invest significant resources or failing that we need to know ***exactly*** what they've told you about the whys and wherefores.

Comment: This original question has been answered (definitely impossible), but from the discussion it seems like theres a couple other questions that are more important than the original but are not clear to me. I'm voting to close this until it's focused into something that is more clearly answerable.

Comment: Either you're not telling us everything we need to know (it's not clear to us why you're so fixated on this _"webhook"_), or it's the classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 8):

Radio transmission is a power hungry endeavor, like previously mentioned that is  not happening simply with the tiny amount of energy you'll be able to harvest when the two magnets pull away, and all of that in the constraints of 2x2 cm, not possible either.